# Are there any compilers for XPath version2 that can dump the execution tree?

Tags: xpath, compiler-construction

I need something that can write out a execution tree for any compiled XPath version 2 expression.

With the program `testXPath` that comes with `libxml2`, you can compile an XPath expression, and then dump the tree that represents the steps for executing that expression. But is's only for XPath version 1.

I have googled for days to find something for XPath version 2, with no luck.

Here is an example with testXPath:

```
testXPath --tree '/foo[@bar="baz"]/horse'
```

Output:

```
  SORT
    COLLECT  'child' 'name' 'node' horse
      COLLECT  'child' 'name' 'node' foo
        ROOT
        PREDICATE
          EQUAL =
            COLLECT  'attributes' 'name' 'node' bar
              NODE
            ELEM Object is a string : baz
              COLLECT  'attributes' 'name' 'node' bar
                NODE
```

Here is is an example with XPath version 2:

```
testXPath --tree '/foo/(bar|baz)'
```

And the result:

```
XPath error : Invalid expression
/foo/(bar|baz)
     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Saxon-EE will export an XML representation of the internal XPath expression tree using the `Expression.export()` method. This supports XPath 3.1.